# What are the approaches to deploy static files so Spray can serve them?

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I have a html page I would like to serve it in spray server.

I am familiar with https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/File-and-Resource-Directives

1. How can I create an archive that can be deployed to Spray (similarly to Tomcat's `.war` files that can be deployed to `webapps` directory)?
2. How to copy files from one directory to other with SBT (like we have copy task for ant build tool)
3. referring to "will serve from a JAR file. In this case client is a directory that has  been packaged in a JAR archive. BTW this works in dev mode without packaging JAR as well."

My project stracture is like

```
src/main/resources/<files to include in main jar here>
src/main/scala/<main Scala sources>
src/main/java/<main Java sources>
src/main/test/resources/<files to include in test jar here>
src/main/scala/<test Scala sources>
src/main/java/<test Java sources>
```

so where I need to keep the directory called "client". where I need to keep my .html files and js files my html refers.

if I issue a package command at SBT interactive mode it will give me jar. how can I run that jar from build.sbt or build.scala

Answer (score 1):

Spray can serve static content as you mentioned. For example:

```
val myRoute =
  get {
    compressResponse()(getFromResourceDirectory("client")) ~
    path("") {
      getFromResource("client/index.html")
    }
  }
```

will serve from a JAR file. In this case `client` is a directory that has been packaged in a JAR archive. BTW this works in dev mode without packaging JAR as well.

There are **2 ways** to run Spray based application, either with **embedded Spray-can server** (JAR file) or in a **container** (WAR file).

If you use Tomcat or some other web container then you can create a regular WAR file with one of the SBT plugins. For example https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin can package WAR files.

If you want to run your web app on a Spray-can server you can use a ready made template for that: https://github.com/spray/spray-template. BTW Spray provides both Jetty and Spray-can based templates there.

You can always use other SBT plugins and create a custom build that will package everything in a WAR or JAR file. One thing to understand about Spray-can is that it's basically a regular application that has a main class which starts up a service that listens on some port (8080) together with an actor system that serves requests, so you don't need any web server or container to run it.

Comment: look at this complete project that packages Spray-can application for an example: https://github.com/pgxcentre/eventhub/. In particular: https://github.com/pgxcentre/eventhub/blob/master/project/Build.scala and https://github.com/pgxcentre/eventhub/blob/master/rest/src/main/scala/ca/pgx/rest/service/EventHub.scala